# Extract part of string using Regex when multiple occurences are found

Tags: regex

String = "

```
(a) its failure to pay is caused by:
(i) administrative or technical error; or
(ii)    a Disruption Event; and
(b) [payment is made within:
(i) (in the case of paragraph (a)(i) above), [5] Business Days of its due date; or
(ii)    (in the case of paragraph (a)(ii) above), [1] Business Days of its due date]/
OR
[payment is made within [ 10 ] Business Days of its due date.]
```

"

Output: [ 10 ] Business Days

Regex which I'm trying = `(?<=payment is made within)(.*)(?=of its due date)`

But these give me 3 lines, I only want that last occurrence, Can anyone help.

Code in Asp.net which i'm trying:

```
        string regularExpressionPattern = RegExPattern.ToString();
        string inputText = FinalPara.ToString();
        Regex re = new Regex(regularExpressionPattern);
        foreach (Match m in re.Matches(FinalPara))
        {
            Response.Write("Regex Values is :" + m.Groups[1].Value.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Is just matching the digits in the last occurrence an option?

Comment: in 3 line, after "payment is made within" -- number should follow. But in others there is some text and then numbers

Comment: edited the question also, added value as expected..

Comment: It's still not clear, does the part you want to match *always* contain just some digits like that, or does it always come after the only `OR`, or what? Ideally there's some distinguishing factor

Comment: yes comes after OR...

Comment: tried your regex and it gives only last line

Comment: when i try my regex in asp.net, it gives all lines...

Comment: What are regex switches ? Show your asp.net calling code - maybe you have applied /s switch or something...

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas - added the asp.net regex code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Negative Lookahead

Split the search pattern into 2 capture groups and then use a negative lookahead on the second capture group.

---

### Demo

```js
const rgx = /(\[\s*[0-9]+?\s*\])( Business Days)(?![\s\S]*\2)/g;
const str = `
(a) its failure to pay is caused by:
(i) administrative or technical error; or
(ii)    a Disruption Event; and
(b) [payment is made within:
(i) (in the case of paragraph (a)(i) above), [5] Business Days of its due date; or
(ii)    (in the case of paragraph (a)(ii) above), [1] Business Days of its due date]/
OR
[payment is made within [ 10 ] Business Days of its due date.]
`;

let x = str.match(rgx);
    
console.log(x);
```